# how to query parse for all push notifications in swift?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Does anyone know a good tutorial dealing with 1. parse push notification queries 2. in swift

I would like to query parse for all notifications sent to a specific user(these could be sent from different users) and handle the notification data accordingly. Not only would I like to know how to query this but where the code should be. I havent found a good tutorial on google that matches all the criteria.

OR

is there a way to force all the notifications in notification center to open in the app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no API that would allow you to query for sent push notifications directly. You would need to create your own collection in Parse, call it `Notification` or something and whenever you send a notification to a user, create an entry in that table. Then you can query this table and display them to a user to show them a history of the notifications.

Comment: Parse  allows for you to export  your app data in JSON format, just wanted to add this.

Comment: What App Data are you referring to? Exporting Push Notifications was never supported

Comment: I double checked @Björn Kaiser and I suppose you are correct. When it allows for all app data to be exported I was under the assumption that this was inclusive of Push data but I appear to be incorrect.