# How to export push notification data from Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

We just started to use parse cloud platform for our android app for pushing notification to our customers. We are looking to export daily pushed notification from parse.

Is there any way to export data which is shown in push tab on parse dashboard ?

I see there is same thread which were looking same thing but haven't share any solution. (https://parse.com/questions/how-to-export-analytics-push-notifications-sent)

Is there any API or any method to download pushed notification data

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to query parse for all push notifications in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358012/how-to-query-parse-for-all-push-notifications-in-swift)

Comment: I answered the same question here, tl;dr: no there is no API to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358012/how-to-query-parse-for-all-push-notifications-in-swift/31358776#31358776

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, but yes.**

We ran into a similar issue and decided to build a `PushNotifications` class in our Parse database. It tracks the push payload, number of opens, etc. and allows us to export that data for our clients.

It was pretty easy to set up:

1. Create the class
2. Add an object every time you send a push (we use a cloud code method for sending pushes and just added the object creation there)
3. When a user opens the push, we increment a `numberOfOpens` number field on the object

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

[This is an old question but Parse now offers the ability to export your app data in JSON format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G5vB.png) Keep in mind Parse will be more or less dead as of January 28th, 2017.